# I used @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) but inverse side of relation doesn't get deleted

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate inside and PostgreSQL and RDBMS. And I created `User` class and `Role` class. `User` can have multiple roles. I want to delete `Role` which related to deleted `User` so I used
`@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` , but when I delete `user1` in `DBInit` related role has not been deleted and I don't know why. `Role` class is the owner of relation, so `Role` as subordinate class should be deleted too as I use `@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`. After `run()` method in `DBInit` executed I have empty `users` table and empty `users_roles` table as I expected, but `roles` table has still has record. So why is that and to to remove cascade `Role` when I delete `User`? The relation is unidirectional, so I don't need to synchronize anything.

Edit: I use `@ManyToMany` relation so using `orphanRemoval=true` is not my case. `@ManyToMany` annotation doesn't even have `orphanRemoval` parameter.

roles table

| id | roles |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | User |

User.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User
{
    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String email;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Role> roles;
}
```

Role.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int id;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    String roleName;
    
    public Role(String roleName)
    {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>
{
}
```

RoleRepository

```java
@Service
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer>
{
}
```

DBInit.java

```java
@Service
public class DBInit implements CommandLineRunner
{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Override
    public void run(String[] args)
    {
        List<Role> roles1 = new ArrayList<>();
        roles1.add(new Role("User"));
        User user1 = new User("email1@email.com", roles1);
        
        userRepository.save(user1);
        userRepository.delete(user1);
    }
}
```

This is my last 3 hibernate queries, so hibernate tried to delete a record from `roles`, but something goes wrong

```
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        users_roles 
    where
        user_email=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        roles 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        users 
    where
        email=?
```